# Where to find the source tarball for libgfortran3?

Tags: gcc, chrome-os, fortran

I've been using the multithreaded linear algebra package [jblas](https://github.com/mikiobraun/jblas) on Chrome OS, which is called from some Java code. When attempting matrix multiplication via `mmul`, the following error is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.jblas.NativeBlas.dgemm(CCIIID[DII[DIID[DII)V
        at org.jblas.NativeBlas.dgemm(Native Method)
        at org.jblas.SimpleBlas.gemm(SimpleBlas.java:247)
        at org.jblas.DoubleMatrix.mmuli(DoubleMatrix.java:1781)
        at org.jblas.DoubleMatrix.mmul(DoubleMatrix.java:3138)
```

Over on [Github](https://github.com/mikiobraun/jblas/issues/14), we're told that this error is likely due to missing the *libgfortran3* package. I wish to compile it from sources as most downloads appear to be architecture-specific, but  I can't find the tarball anywhere. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of regular [gcc](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/)

```
# wget ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/snapshots/7-20161016/gcc-7-20161016.tar.bz2
# bzip2 -d gcc-7-20161016.tar.bz2
# tar tvf gcc-7-20161016.tar |grep libgfortran|head
-rw-r--r-- gccadmin/gcc    5750 2016-09-23 20:36 gcc-7-20161016/gcc/fortran/libgfortran.h
drwxr-xr-x gccadmin/gcc       0 2016-10-16 22:32 gcc-7-20161016/libgfortran/
drwxr-xr-x gccadmin/gcc       0 2016-10-16 22:32 gcc-7-20161016/libgfortran/config/
-rw-r--r-- gccadmin/gcc   12505 2016-01-04 14:30 gcc-7-20161016/libgfortran/config/fpu-387.h
-rw-r--r-- gccadmin/gcc    7835 2016-01-04 14:30 gcc-7-20161016/libgfortran/config/fpu-aix.h
-rw-r--r-- gccadmin/gcc    9161 2016-01-04 14:30 gcc-7-20161016/libgfortran/config/fpu-glibc.h
-rw-r--r-- gccadmin/gcc    8046 2016-01-04 14:30 gcc-7-20161016/libgfortran/config/fpu-sysv.h
-rw-r--r-- gccadmin/gcc    2714 2016-01-04 14:30 gcc-7-20161016/libgfortran/config/fpu-generic.h
-rw-r--r-- gccadmin/gcc   13099 2014-06-17 03:55 gcc-7-20161016/libgfortran/ChangeLog-2013
drwxr-xr-x gccadmin/gcc       0 2016-10-16 22:32 gcc-7-20161016/libgfortran/generated/
#
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution above, it's crucial to note that [jblas](http://jblas.org/) also imposes the following runtime dependencies.

**Required**:

```
gfortran-4.6 libgfortran3
```

**Optional**:

```
gfortran-multilib gfortran-doc gfortran-4.6-multilib gfortran-4.6-doc libgfortran3-dbg
```